# Unknown column 'getContent.movie_id' in 'field list

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, express-graphql

my whole schema

```
const Films =  new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'films',
  interfaces: () => [MovieStream],

  fields: () => ({
    movie_id: {
        type: GraphQLString,

      },
    id:{
        type: GraphQLID
      },
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString,

      },

    })
})
Films._typeConfig = {
    sqlTable: "films",
    uniqueKey: 'id',

  }

  const MovieStream = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: 'MovieStream',

    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: GraphQLID,

          },

          movie_id: {
              type: GraphQLString,

            },       
    })


})

      MovieStream._typeConfig = {
        sqlTable: "movie_streams",
        uniqueKey: 'id'
      }


      const QueryRoot = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Query',
        fields: () => ({
          getContentList:{
              type: new GraphQLList(Films),
              args: {
                id: {
                  type: GraphQLInt
                },
                permalink: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                },
                language: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                },
                content_types_id: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                },
                oauth_token:{
                    type: GraphQLString
                }

              },

              resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {

                               return joinMonster.default(resolveInfo,{}, sql => {
                                  return FilmDb.query(sql).then(function(result) { 

                                      return result[0];
                                  });   
                              } ,{dialect: 'mysql'});          
              },

          }

        })
      })

      module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
          query: QueryRoot
      })
```

I have again modified my code still got the error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown column 'getContent.movie_id' in 'field list'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getContentList"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "getContentList": null
  }
}
```

My previous post [Is it possible to fetch data from multiple tables using GraphQLList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117230/is-it-possible-to-fetch-data-from-multiple-tables-using-graphqllist/55118075?noredirect=1#comment97020720_55118075)

Please check and tell me where i am wrong??? I have already add the field still it does not access the field of that object type

Comment: @MarcoDaniels this is the error

Comment: This error is not related to the GraphQL part, it's database related. Does the column `movie_id` actually exists on your database? Can you provide the models?

Comment: movie_id is in movieStream table field i am just fetchinging it through interface. Is it the wrong way?